# Codigniter update every row in table with different ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a configuration table in a database, using CI3.

Each row has a unique ID, as well as a type_name and type_desc.

So as each row has a unique ID, how can I update the entire table using one update_batch query?

I obviously don't want to run a query on each row, so I'm guessing i need to build an array with the values, but how can do this with the where clause somehow within the array?! Confused.

I basically need to do this:

```
UPDATE check_types
SET type_name = POSTED_TYPE_NAME, type_desc = POSTED_TYPE_DESC
WHERE check_type_id = ???? POSTED_ID?????
```

Comment: For updating each row no need of where clause . Just use `UPDATE check_types
SET type_name = POSTED_TYPE_NAME, type_desc = POSTED_TYPE_DESC` it will update every row of table

Comment: But this doesn't update the row dependent on the ID?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to extend the db driver.

In the core folder create file with name MY_DB_mysqli_driver.php. file name assumes that the subclass_prefix defined in config.php is MY_

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_DB_mysqli_driver extends CI_DB_mysqli_driver
{
    final public function __construct($params)
    {
        parent::__construct($params);
    }

    /**
     * Insert_On_Duplicate_Key_Update_Batch
     *
     * Compiles batch insert strings and runs the queries
     *
     * @param    string $table Table to insert into
     * @param    array $set An associative array of insert values
     * @param    bool $escape Whether to escape values and identifiers
     * @return    int    Number of rows inserted or FALSE on failure
     */
    public function insert_on_duplicate_update_batch($table = '', $set = NULL, $escape = NULL)
    {
        if ($set !== NULL)
        {
            $this->set_insert_batch($set, '', $escape);
        }

        if (count($this->qb_set) === 0)
        {
            // No valid data array. Folds in cases where keys and values did not match up
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_use_set') : FALSE;
        }

        if ($table === '')
        {
            if (!isset($this->qb_from[0]))
            {
                return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_set_table') : FALSE;
            }

            $table = $this->qb_from[0];
        }

        // Batch this baby
        $affected_rows = 0;
        for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->qb_set); $i < $total; $i += 100)
        {
            $this->query($this->_insert_on_duplicate_key_update_batch($this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, $escape, FALSE), $this->qb_keys, array_slice($this->qb_set, $i, 100)));
            $affected_rows += $this->affected_rows();
        }

        $this->_reset_write();
        return $affected_rows;
    }

    /**
     * Insert on duplicate key update batch statement
     *
     * Generates a platform-specific insert string from the supplied data
     *
     * @param    string $table Table name
     * @param    array $keys INSERT keys
     * @param    array $values INSERT values
     * @return    string
     */
    private function _insert_on_duplicate_key_update_batch($table, $keys, $values)
    {
        foreach ($keys as $num => $key)
        {
            $update_fields[] = $key . '= VALUES(' . $key . ')';
        }
        return "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode(', ', $keys) . ") VALUES " . implode(', ', $values) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " . implode(', ', $update_fields);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
$sql_array = array();
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $arr = array(
            'check_type_id' => $row['check_type_id'], 
            'type_name' => $row['type_name'], 
            'type_desc' => $row['type_desc'] 
    );
    $sql_array[] = $arr;
}
$this->db->insert_on_duplicate_update_batch('check_types', $sql_array);
```